# Wait for http post to end using promise

Tags: node.js, rest

I am learning to use http post and trying to wait for it to end using promise.  But I can't get it to work, please help:

```
var http = require('http');
const auth = () => {
  var post_data = JSON.stringify({
      "username": "aaa",
      "password": "bbb"
  });
  const options = { 
    host: 'http://1.1.1.1',
    path: '/v1/authentication',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Content-Length': post_data.length
    }
  };

  const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    var body = '';
    res.on('data', d => {
      body += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
      console.log("Response body", body);
    });
  });

  req.on('error', error => {
    console.error("error", error);
  });

  req.write(post_data)
  req.end();

  return Promise.resolve("!!");
};
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  return auth().then((res)=>{
    res.status(200).send(res);
  });
};
```

Entry point is the hellWorld function.  What should I do to wait for the http post to finish and get the response result using promise?

Comment: you will have to wrap your http request into 
    
   return  new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    //here your http request
       //after successful add resolve(data) 
    })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here i did some for get api call.

```
try {

    const auth = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const options = {
                host: 'api.github.com',
                path: '/orgs/nodejs',
                port: 443,
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'User-Agent': 'request'
                }
            };
            const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
                res.setEncoding('utf8');
                res.on('data', d => {
                    resolve(d)
                });
            });

            req.on('error', error => {
                console.error("error", error);
            });
            req.end();
        })
    };

    const data = await auth()
    console.log('should execute first', data)
    console.log('should executed after http call')
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

you can modify above code with your, just you have to wrap your http call inside Promises.
comment down if any its a solution, and mark as a solution